# No soul will bear the burden of other? hadith vs Quran contradiction

Tags: hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, sahih-muslim, contradiction

> **Sahih Muslim Book 37. Repentance And Exhortation Of Repentance**
>
> Abu Burda reported on the authority of his father that Allah's Apostle
>   (may peace be upon him) said: No Muslim would die but Allah would
>   admit in his stead a Jew or a Christian in Hell-Fire. 'Umar b. Abd
>   al-'Aziz took an oath: By One besides Whom there is no god but He,
>   thrice that his father had narrated that to him from Allah's Messenger
>   (may peace be upon him).

Now this contradict with the following Quranic verse

> "Say: What! shall I seek a Lord other than God? And He is the Lord of
>   all things; and no soul earns (evil) but against itself, and no bearer
>   of burden shall bear the burden of another; then to your Lord is your
>   return, so He will inform you of that in which you differed"
>
> Quran (006:164)

Do I have to accept this hadith as authentic even it is in direct contradiction to Quranic Verses because scholars accept this hadith as authentic?

Comment: Where's the contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

When scholars call a hadith authentic, it is usually according to *sanad* i.e. the chain of narrators. There still remains the task of validating the *matn* i.e. the reported content in the light of Qur'an and other factors. It is a known practice. For example, [Al-Khatib al-Baghdadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Khatib_al-Baghdadi) (392–463AH) writes in al-Kifaya:

> ولا يقبل خبر الواحد في منافاة حكم العقل وحكم القرآن الثابت المحكم ,
>   والسنة المعلومة , والفعل الجاري مجرى السنة , وكل دليل مقطوع به
>
> A khabr-i wahid (a technical alias of hadith) cannot be accepted which is against sense and
>   intellect, is against an established and explicit directive of the
>   Qur’an, is against a known Sunnah or is against a practice which is
>   observed like the Sunnah or its conflict with some conclusive argument
>   becomes absolutely evident.

(I could not find its translation in English. Here is an [indirect reference](http://www.renaissance.com.pk/JulHadi2y6.htm).)

Therefore, being against the Qur'an you may not accept it. You may also look for its explanation that does not contradict the Qur'an.

[Al-Nawawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi) (631–676 AH) also notes this contradiction in his commentary of Sahih Muslim and interprets this and similar hadiths in the light of another hadith:

> لكل أحد منزل في الجنة ومنزل في النار فالمؤمن إذا دخل الجنة خلفه الكافر
>   في النار **لاستحقاقه ذلك بكفره**
>
> For everyone there is a place in the Paradise and a place in Hell.
>   When a believer enters Paradise a Kafir takes his place in Hell
>   **because he deserved it due to his Kufr**.

(A variant of this hadith is available [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/1344840).)

Hence, according to this explanation the Jews and Christians will go to Hell only due to their own beliefs which is in accordance with the Qur'anic principle.